# Запятая или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Хотелось бы узнать() у вас имеется такой товар в наличии?

После таких слов обычно ставится запятая или двоеточие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно ставить двоеточие: Хотелось бы узнать: у вас имеется такой товар в наличии? Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, прямой вопрос, изъяснительное значение.

ОТВЕТ (с учетом ситуации)

Мне нужны лыжи (называется марка). Хотелось бы узнать, у вас имеется такой товар в наличии?
При отсутствии предупредительной паузы "хотелось бы узнать" можно считать вводным предложением со значением этикета.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

"Хотелось бы узнать: у вас имеется такой товар в наличии". Такой вариант без вопросительного знака НЕ ПОДОЙДЕТ, так как противоречит правилам -  в БСП обязательно ставится вопросительный знак, этот вариант даже носит название "прямого вопроса".

Вот, кажется, несложная задача, но она становится поводом для оценки эффективности различных методик. И я вновь хочу обратить внимание коллег на интонационно-структурный (грамматический) анализ предложений. Здесь нет жесткой привязки к правилам, но нет и необоснованной свободы действий. В данном случае мы совершенно законно можем использовать две хорошо известные грамматические формы и "прослушать" их. Мы наглядно видим, как "правят" правилами разные оттенки смысла и как изменения в интонации устной речи отражаются на письме.

Answer (score 9):

В этом бессоюзном предложении между частями нужно двоеточие. *Хотелось бы узнать( что именно?): у вас имеется такой товар в наличии?* Вторая часть поясняет, раскрывает смысл первой. Можно переделать в сложноподчиненное и поставить запятую. *Хотелось бы узнать, имеется **ли** у вас такой товар в наличии.*

Answer (score 4):

По правилам, если считать первую часть главным предложением, то да, двоеточие.
Но я боюсь, что смысл этого оборота давно перестал быть существенным для говорящего и превратился в обычную вводную "этикетную", конструкцию, типа "позвольте поинтересоваться" или как в известном сериале - "стесняюсь спросить".

Посему - я за запятую. Но вообще контекст бы...

Comment: Название товара. Хотелось бы узнать() у вас имеется такой товар в наличии? 

или

Хотелось бы узнать() у вас имеется такой товар в наличии()название товара.

Допустим,такие ситуации.

Comment: *Хотелось бы узнать, у вас имеется такой товар в наличии?* 
или
*Хотелось бы узнать: у вас имеется такой товар в наличии.* 
Лучше первое

*Хотелось бы узнать, у вас имеется такой товар в наличии: название товара.*  

имхо. Спорить с авторитетами тут не буду, ибо правила я знаю, но здесь "не лезут" они в ситуацию.

Comment: А потому что все правила рассчитаны на речь книжную. Если мы говорим о фиксации устной разговорной речи, то да, вполне допустимо поставить запятую.Действительно, первая часть сближается с этикетным "скажите, пожалуйста"